# Why do int arrays bound with 'def' accept Long values in Clojure?

Tags: arrays, clojure, interop, long-integer

I've noticed that if I `def` an int array and set an element in the array with a Long, then there are no complaints.  However if I bind the int array in a `let` block set an element with a Long, then an IllegalArgument exception is thrown.  Could someone help me understand why this is?

The code below demonstrates the discrepancy. I tried it in both Clojure 1.8 and the latest beta version of 1.9 and got these results.

```clj
(def a (int-array 10))
(aset a 0 Long/MAX_VALUE) ;; sets first element to -1

(let [b (int-array 10)]
  (aset b 0 Long/MAX_VALUE)) ;; throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for int:
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This discrepancy is caused because type inference is occurring in the `let`, but not in the `def`. You can verify this by using type hints to switch the situation around:

```
(def ^"[I" a (int-array 10))
(aset a 0 Long/MAX_VALUE)
;; throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for int:

(let [^Object b (int-array 10)]
  (aset b 0 Long/MAX_VALUE))
;; sets first element to -1
```

Or, alternatively:

```
(def a (int-array 10))
(aset ^"[I" a 0 Long/MAX_VALUE)
;; throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for int:

(let [b (int-array 10)]
  (aset ^Object b 0 Long/MAX_VALUE))
;; sets first element to -1
```

This is because [Clojure inlines calls to `aset` when possible](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3793-L3803), which includes all these cases, but the inlined static method call [has many overloads](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L2203-L2342).

Comment: Setting the element to `-1` looks like a bug to me: you are silently getting *unchecked* arithmetic.

Comment: @Thumbnail I agree; it seems like a bug along the same lines as [CLJ-1142](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1142).